# Invalid argument supplied for foreach(), is_array() returns true

Tags: php

I have the following code, and I can't figure out what's wrong with it. I am supplying an array as an argument, and is_array($primes) returns true. Anything I'm missing here?

```
function generate_primes($max)
{
$i = 4;
$primes = [2, 3];


while($i < $max)
{
    $isPrime = true;

    foreach($primes as $value)
    {
        if($i % $value == 0)
        {
            $isPrime = false;
            break;
        }

    }
    if($isPrime)
        $primes = $i;

    $i++;
}

return $primes;

}
```

Comment: `$primes = [2, 3];` is not valid, use `$primes = array(2, 3)`

Comment: @Akam: Short array syntax is valid if he's using PHP 5.4 or higher. References: [1](http://php.net/manual/en/migration54.new-features.php), [2](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

Comment: This is incorrect; `$primes = [2, 3];` is supported by newer versions of PHP.

Answer (score 2):

`$primes = $i;` shows that you re-assign the `$primes` variable after you find your first prime, 5. It no longer is an array at this point.

Instead, use this:

```
if($isPrime)
    array_push($primes,$i);
```

Comment: Thank you so much, this has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Use php array type:

```
$primes = array(2, 3);
```

then later, when adding a new prime to the array:

```
array_push($primes, $i);
```